# Updating Facebook app settings via Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a problem with updating app settings via Graph API using Javascript SDK. I followed the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app) and tried this code:

```
FB.api(
    "/APP_ID/?access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET",
    "POST",
    {
        "object": {
            "canvas_url": "Test about text",
            "migrations": "{'secure_stream_urls': true}",
            "restrictions": "{'age': '21+', 'type': 'alcohol'}"
        }
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    }
);
```

The response is `true` but I see no changes in the application settings page in Facebook Developers (no matter which properties I am trying to change).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `object`-

```
FB.api(
   "/APP_ID/?access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET",
   "POST",
   {
      "canvas_url": "Test about text",
      "migrations": "{'secure_stream_urls': true}",
      "restrictions": "{'age': '21+', 'type': 'alcohol'}"
   },
   function (response) {
     //if (response && !response.error) {
       console.log(response);   // console the complete response for any errors
     //}
   }
);
```