# Changing the Facebook application's basic settings using Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Since I'm new to `Facebook API`, I've been researching a lot on it's documentation, and found a way, according to documentation, to change basic application's settings. Here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application

So i tried this first:

```
$.post('/v2.5/'+appSec,{canvas_url:'https://apps.facebook.com/ognjen', secure_canvas_url:'https://renotifier.com/canvas/399/ognjen'});
```

It is a `HTTP` call to certain endpoint of `Graph API`.

And this afterwards:

```
    var appSec = $('#appSec').val();
    var appId = $('#appId').val();
    console.log(appSec, appId);// catches everything totally fine

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
         FB.init({
         appId: appSec,
         cookie: true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                                               // the session
         xfbml: true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                                version: 'v2.5' // use version 2.2
                            });

         FB.api(
              "/"+appId+"/?access_token="+appId+"|"+appSec,
              "POST",
              {
                 "canvas_url": "https://apps.facebook.com/ognjen",
                 "secure_canvas_url": "https://ognjen.com/canvas/ognjen/"
              }
              ,
              function (response) {
              if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log(response);
              }
              }
              );
}
```

But none of this attempts succeed. I've also found similar questions here: [How to change user's app settings on developers facebook profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476011/how-to-change-users-app-settings-on-developers-facebook-profile), and here:[Updating Facebook app settings via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308020/updating-facebook-app-settings-via-graph-api?rq=1) and tried their answers but it didn't work. Someone with good knowledge of Graph API, please help, I'm pretty stuck.

**UPDATE**:

Just in case someone didn't figure out, I'm trying to change already set up `canvas_url` and `secure_canvas_url` of `Facebook` app.

Comment: The only mistake i see is that one: appId: appSec. Which you probably already found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working gist:

https://gist.github.com/goranefbl/bbed8c255de9cbd91c92

btw. it does work without calling it as callback for event.subscribe.

Comment: Thanks for help, but this throws an error now. `Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not permitted by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

Comment: You need to run it from server instead as a file/simple html, that worked for me. I think its refering to the js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";

Comment: I have the whole project up and running on server already(not localhost) if you referred to that...

Comment: Btw, this is what error object consists of : `error: Object
code: 190
fbtrace_id: "Dz5M9gqpZKN"
message: "Invalid OAuth access token."
type: "OAuthException"`

Comment: And also, when i paste this into browser: `https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&amp;access_token=474124136110135|023f308345f945b9f3ff785c17cc2d87` which are real id and secret for my app it shows this error:`{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803,
      "fbtrace_id": "CSTbks4jPbc"
   }
}` So the bug can be due to app not setting properly

Comment: Correct, that might be settings part in the app itself. Regarding first given url error, it must be run from the site url that was added inside apps settings, in my case it was localhost and thats why it was working from localhost. That can also be error regarding "Invalid OAuth access token." type: "OAuthException". If you are redirecting to some address other then authorised by your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the App Access Token in the POST json instead:

```
{
    "canvas_url": "https://apps.facebook.com/ognjen",
    "secure_canvas_url": "https://ognjen.com/canvas/ognjen/",
    "access_token": appId + "|" + appSec
}
```